# Ctrl+Shift+End android input keyevent

Tags: android, adb, keyevent

I would like to select all the text to the end by adb

```
input keyevent --longpress 114
input keyevent --longpress 59
input keyevent 93
```

To select all text to the end but it didn't work.

Maybe Ctrl+Shift+End is not the shortcut for the selection to the end?

Comment: Does it needs a clarification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `input keyevent --longpress` is not working.
However `input keycombination 114 59 93` it worked.